# Spring Boot not autodeployed on startup (tomcat)

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have a spring boot application packaged in war, and I have a production tomcat with `autoDeploy=false` and `deployOnStartup=true` and when i copy my war into the deployments folder it doesn't deploys anything nor logs.

But i set `autoDeploy` to `true` and I copy same war it's deployed fine.

Any idea?

This is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <namejavaser</name>    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.13.1</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Because that is what you configured it to do... Do not auto deploy...

Comment: But it doesn't deploy on startup neither but war it's in tomcat/webapps directory before..

Comment: That is not what you mention in your question (although it is in your title). But isn't deployments only used for auto deployment? Been a while since I used a stand alone tomcat :).

Comment: I said -> and deployOnStartup=true but maybe it's not clear enough.
With this flag i mean all war files being inside webapps folder while startup will be deployed, right?

Comment: As stated probably not clear. But if you don't want auto deploy you will need to manually add the applications to startup info of Tomcat (in the global server.xml) at least if I recall correctly. At least in `deployments` it won't do much as that is for auto-deployments (if I recall correctly).